# Replace addEventListener

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have a lot of code that use `addEventListener` in minified libraries, files ..., but I need to make work this code in **IE8**, so replacing `addEventListener` with `addEvent`:

```
 /*
  * Register the specified handler function to handle events of the specified
  * type on the specified target. Ensure that the handler will always be
  * invoked as a method of the target.
  */
 function addEvent(type, handler) {
     if (this.addEventListener)
         this.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
     else {
         this.attachEvent("on" + type,
             function(event) {
                 return handler.call(this, event);
             });
     }
 }
```

I can "override" `window.addEventListener`, but how can I override this method in the other objects?

Thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: you can define window.addEventListener in IE to work as the W3 one, so that all code uses the same code, and new browsers use the native command instead of forking each time.

Comment: window.addEventListener = window.addEventListener || function addEvent(type, handler) {
            this.attachEvent("on" + type,
                    function (event) {
                        return handler.call(this, event);
            });
}

Comment: if i use above code only add addEventListener to window? I need to all objects

Comment: yeah, the above is just for window. you should use Object.defineProperty to do the same type of thing on Element.prototype (only for IE!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access it the same way as you would in modern browsers, you'll want to add the method to `Window`, `HTMLDocument`, and `Element` prototypes.

```
(function(){
    if (!("addEventListener" in window)) {
        function addEventListener(type, handler) {
            var _this = this;              
            this.attachEvent("on" + type, function(){
                handler.call(_this, window.event);  
            });
        }
        Window.prototype.addEventListener = addEventListener;
        HTMLDocument.prototype.addEventListener = addEventListener;
        Element.prototype.addEventListener = addEventListener;
    }
})();
```

<sub>Note: while we've normalized access to the function and addressed the `this` issue, we haven't normalized the event to w3c standards. So, it will be missing properties like `event.target`, `event.relatedTarget`, etc.


Check out Mozilla's [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Compatibility) shim.</sub>

Comment: you can modify protos to behave like other browsers without the risk that stems from creating your own brand-new property names waiting to conflict one day. since that name is already taken, you don't have to worry. IE8 supporte Object.defineProperty on Element protos (it's about the only place it actually works), so you can also avoid the pesky "you broke my for-in" complaints that have long been associated with modifying native object prototypes.